# angularjs - Manipulate dom

Tags: angularjs, dom, getelementbyid

I have a textarea that remains ng-empty despite adding a comment through a function. As a result the content is not being binded to the $scope and I am losing the data.

I have tried the following:

```
angular.element($document[0].getElementById(vm.selectedId)).value = comment;

$document[0].getElementById(vm.selectedId).value = comment;

window.document.getElementById(vm.selectedId).value = comment;

document.getElementById(vm.selectedId).value = comment;
```

The first effort doesn't work whatsoever (despite having the most ng wrapping.) The rest will appear in the field but do not bind.

I should also note that the text fields that I am trying to add text to are within rows of ng-repeat and so their id's are created using $index...

Comment: do you have `id="{{$index}}"` or `ng-attr-id="{{$index}}"`? (any specific reason why you need to use the `id` instead of `ng-model`?)

Comment: um, use ng-model like it is suppose to be when you are trying to bind to controller. <textarea ng-model="textAreaModel"></textarea> This should allow for 2 data binding.

Comment: I'm using `ng-attr-id`. I believe I need to use `id` because I'm binding property instances within `ng-repeat`rather than normal properties...

Comment: Dante, I am using ng-model also. It is not binding for the reasons I have already explained.

Comment: @jamesbcn it would be nice to see your HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about passing the index to your function and then updating the underlying array

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

   function myCtrl(){
       /* jshint validthis: true */
       var vm=this;
       vm.items = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
       vm.addComment = function(i){
        vm.items[i] = 'comment';
       }
       
   } 

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by $index">
            <textarea ng-model=item></textarea>
            <button ng-click="vm.addComment($index)">add comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That would work but unfortunately I also need sorting functionality: `ng-repeat="comp in deskCtrl.desktop.comparables.comp track by $index | toArray | orderBy:deskCtrl.sortTables.comparables.sortType:deskCtrl.sortTables.comparables.sortReverse">`

Comment: @jamesbcn if they are filtered, try passing the filtered array as well: `ng-repeat="item in filtered = (items | toArray | ...)"` then use `ng-click="addComment(filtered, $index)"`

Comment: I've managed to finally crack how to bind to properties of objects on an ng-repeat (simply by passing them through a function). Thank you all. Never again will I even consider using $index!